# Badly Formed HTML: How to NOT show a bullet on an empty li element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some html that is created/output from a flash application & I need to show/render it in firefox.

The HTML is badly formed, so it will spit out empty **li** elements & lists with no **ul or ol** elements but it will spit out the **li** elements.

**Is there a css flag or any method to not show a li bullet if the li element is empty(see code example of what *empty* means below)?**

If a li element has no innerText, then it shows the bullet. But I dont want it to do that, I want it to NOT show the bullet if there is no innerText in the li element. Is there any way to do this without having to parse HTML?

```
// example of badly formed HTML output from flash
<textformat leading="2">
    <li>
        <font style=" font-family: 'arial'; font-size: 14px; color: #FFFFFF; letter-spacing: 0px; ">
            <b>Influence and Negotiation</b>
            <font style=" font-size: 12px; color: #000000; ">
            </font>
        </font>
    </li>
</textformat>

// sometimes I get an empty li element, which in Firefox shows the bullet. I want to NOT show the bullet/li element if it is empty
<textformat leading="2">
    <li>
        <font style=" font-family: 'arial'; font-size: 14px; color: #FFFFFF; letter-spacing: 0px; ">
            <!-- empty li element -->
        </font>
    </li>
</textformat>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the empty li elements (where "empty" means none or only whitespace content), you could do:

```
function getText(el) {
  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    return el.textContent;
  }
  if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    return el.innerText;
  }
}

var li, lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var re = /^\s*$/;

for (var i=0, iLen=lis.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  li = lis[i];

  if (re.test(getText(li))) {
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could set the empty LIs to:

```
 list-style-type: none;
```

by adding a suitable class, but results might not be consistent across browsers. Some will leave a space for the empty li, some will remove it. You could also use a class with:

```
 display: none;
```

to leave the li there but not display it and not have a space. It's up to you.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't a way. There's `:empty` but that doesn't work when there's a `<font>` element beneath it, and there's no `:has` in CSS. You can use `:has` with jQuery, though, and since you've tagged it [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) I assume it's an option:

```
$('li:has(font:empty)').remove();
```

Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').each(function(){
      if($(this).html().length == 0)
          $(this).css('list-style-type','none')                        
   });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yU8aJ/